# How to catch the base exception and show on the UI - java

Tags: java, swing, exception

I have a swing application in which the user selects a database from the JComboBox and provides a query in JTextArea and on the click of button results are shown in JTable.

The code of button click

```
private void jbtnRunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try
    {
    jtbResults.setModel(objtrm.runQuery(jcbRepository.getSelectedItem().toString(), jtaQuery.getText()));

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }
}
```

In this code `objtrm.runQuery`is in the methods class for this UI.
This method takes the database name and query, calls another method from different class which returns `ResultSet` from this query and database name(connection strings are stored in database), converts this `ResultSet` to `DefaultTableModel` and returns it.

Now if a network issue comes up, my class method which returns `ResultSet` throws `IOException` but all i see on the JOptionPane is error `Cannot set a null Table model`. the actual stacktrace in the console is

> java.sql.SQLException: JZ006: Caught IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: au201d002v

i want to show the user this exception rather than what i get.
Are there different approaches to handle this case, or are there any direct methods from `Exception` class that can give the root cause.

I tried `e.getCause`, it returns nothing.

EDIT
runQuery method

```
 public DefaultTableModel runQuery(String repoName,String query)
    {
        DefaultTableModel model =null;
        new LoggingManager().addToLog("TestRepositoryUI Methods RunQuery");
    try
    {
        RepositoryManager rm = new RepositoryManager();
        Repository r = rm.getRepositoryByName(repoName);
        ResultSet rs = rm.Repo_to_ResultSet(r.RepoID, query);
         model  = new BuildTableModel().build(rs);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        new LoggingManager().addToLog(e);
    }
        return model;
}
```

repo_to_resultset method (It is this method that will surely give IOException as i am not connected to the network.)

```
 case "Sybase":
             try
         {
             new LoggingManager().addToLog("RM Repo_To_ResultSet() Sybase");
             Connection conn=null;
             Statement s;

             String connString = objRe.ConString;
             Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver");
            conn =     DriverManager.getConnection(connString,"username","pass");
            s = conn.createStatement();
            s.execute(query);
            rs = s.getResultSet();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
             new LoggingManager().addToLog(e);
         }
         break;
```

Thanks

Comment: To check the catch exactly, do `System.err.println("---");` before printStacktrace. You may be catching that IOException and then either throw it away, or wrap it in your own exception - without passing the original exception (the cause) as exception constructor parameter. It would make sense to repair that point. Maybe the stacktrace you saw happened earlier.

Comment: Are you sure `runQuery` really throws the exception? Can you show its code?

Comment: @RealSkeptic run query calls database related methods class, which queries the database and returns resultset. It is that class that generates that exception.. I will include the code

Comment: added the code @RealSkeptic

Answer (score 1):

The Exception class's printStackTrace() method, which is what is getting printed in the console for you, is a combination of the exceptions toString() method and getStackTrace() method.

If you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()) of printStackTrace(), it tells you where it's getting the values it prints out. Going off of this documentation you can take an exception and format it in the way similar to the printStackTrace() output.

```
    ...
} catch(Exception e) {
    String trace = e.toString() + "\n";
    for(StackTraceElement element : e.getStackTrace())
        trace += element.toString() + "\n";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, trace, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: this gives the same error `cannot set a null table model`. i need user to know that there was a `IOException`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `runQuery` method does not throw the exception. Instead, it *handles* it. This means the exception will never get to the `catch` clause in `jbtnRunActionPerformed`.

Instead, if there was an error, `runQuery` never reaches the line

```
     model  = new BuildTableModel().build(rs);
```

when there is an exception. The exception is *handled* inside the `catch` of `runQuery`, the stack trace is printed and the exception is logged. But that's it - once you have handled the exception, it is not propagated. The code continues to the line

```
    return model;
```

And the `model` variable is null. So that's what the `jbtnRunActionPerformed` sees. It never sees the exception.

In order to let an upper level handle the exception, you need to **throw** it. It means you have to declare `runQuery` as `throws IOException`.

Furthermore, you should not ever catch `Exception`. You should always catch only the exceptions that are really expected from the part of the code inside the `try`. Your IDE is supposed to help you with that.

- Let a method throw the exceptions that happen inside it if you want to handle them at an upper level, by *not* using a `try...catch` for those exceptions and instead using `throws` at the method header.
- Handle only specific exceptions in any `catch` clause.

Note that you are doing the same inside your `RepositoryManager` method, so you should start fixing it from there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `runQuery()` method is catching the exception and printing it to the console, then returning `null`. Then in your `jbtnRunActionPerformed()` method that `null` is being passed to `jtbResults.setModel(),` which causes the error you are seeing in your JOptionPane.

So either show the JOptionPane in the catch block of `runQuery()`  or have `runQuery()` re-throw the exception so it will be caught in `jbtnRunActionPerformed()` before it tries to pass a null to `setModel().`